# constant hue based interpolation opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

recently I am learning how to convert a Bayer image to an RGB image. I know there are several ways to do it:

1. bilinear interpolation;
2. freeman's improvement of bilinear interpolation;
3. constant hue based interpolation;
4. gradient based Interpolation;
5. etc ...

I learned the above from a paper named "[Demosaicking methods for Bayer color arrays](https://www.ece.ncsu.edu/imaging/Publications/2002/demosaicking-JEI-02.pdf)".

But when I try to implement the **constant hue based interpolation** approach, I encountered an issue. According to the paper, the result of that approach should be better than the result from simple bilinear interpolation. Unfortunately, I got the opposite result. Here is the result from my program:

I don't have enough reputation to put a image, here is a link to the result image >> [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYRJT.jpg)

My program is following:

```
import cv2 as cv

def hue_constant_interpolation(_mosaic):
    _mosaic = cv.normalize(_mosaic.astype('double'), None, 0.0, 1.0, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
    # split the image into three channel
    b, g, r = cv.split(_mosaic)

    # set the value which is useless to 0
    b = fill_with_zero_b(b)
    g = fill_with_zero_g(g)
    r = fill_with_zero_r(r)

    # do the linear interpolation for green channel
    g = bilinear_interpolation_g(g)

    # using the estimated green channel to calculate
    # the red and blue channels, hue has been interpolated
    g = cv.copyMakeBorder(g, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv.BORDER_REFLECT)
    b = hue_constant_channel_b(b, g)
    r = hue_constant_channel_r(r, g)

    return cv.merge((b, g, r))


def hue_constant_channel_r(estimating, interpolated):
    estimating = cv.copyMakeBorder(estimating, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv.BORDER_REFLECT)
    e_row_num = len(estimating)
    for row in range(1, e_row_num - 1):
        e_col_num = len(estimating[row])
        interpolated_row_median = np.median(interpolated[row])
        for col in range(1, e_col_num - 1):
            if row % 2 != 0 and col % 2 == 0:
                if estimating[row][col] == 0:
                    g1 = interpolated[row][col - 1]
                    g2 = interpolated[row][col + 1]
                    estimating[row][col] = 0.5 * interpolated[row][col] * (
                        estimating[row][col - 1] / (g1 if g1 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row][col + 1] / (g2 if g2 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                    )

            elif row % 2 == 0 and col % 2 != 0:
                if estimating[row][col] == 0:
                    g1 = interpolated[row - 1][col]
                    g2 = interpolated[row + 1][col]
                    estimating[row][col] = 0.5 * interpolated[row][col] * (
                        estimating[row - 1][col] / (g1 if g1 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row + 1][col] / (g2 if g2 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                    )

            elif row % 2 == 0 and col % 2 == 0:
                if estimating[row][col] == 0:
                    g1 = interpolated[row - 1][col - 1]
                    g2 = interpolated[row - 1][col + 1]
                    g3 = interpolated[row + 1][col - 1]
                    g4 = interpolated[row + 1][col + 1]
                    estimating[row][col] = 0.25 * interpolated[row][col] * (
                        estimating[row - 1][col - 1] / (g1 if g1 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row - 1][col + 1] / (g2 if g2 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row + 1][col - 1] / (g3 if g3 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row + 1][col + 1] / (g4 if g4 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                    )

    return estimating


def hue_constant_channel_b(estimating, interpolated):
    estimating = cv.copyMakeBorder(estimating, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv.BORDER_REFLECT)
    e_row_num = len(estimating)
    for row in range(1, e_row_num - 1):
        e_col_num = len(estimating[row])
        interpolated_row_median = np.median(interpolated[row])
        for col in range(1, e_col_num - 1):
            if row % 2 == 0 and col % 2 != 0:
                if estimating[row][col] == 0:
                    g1 = interpolated[row][col - 1]
                    g2 = interpolated[row][col + 1]
                    estimating[row][col] = 0.5 * interpolated[row][col] * (
                        estimating[row][col - 1] / (g1 if g1 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row][col + 1] / (g2 if g2 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                    )

            elif row % 2 != 0 and col % 2 == 0:
                if estimating[row][col] == 0:
                    g1 = interpolated[row - 1][col]
                    g2 = interpolated[row + 1][col]
                    estimating[row][col] = 0.5 * interpolated[row][col] * (
                        estimating[row - 1][col] / (g1 if g1 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row + 1][col] / (g2 if g2 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                    )

            elif row % 2 != 0 and col % 2 != 0:
                if estimating[row][col] == 0:
                    g1 = interpolated[row - 1][col - 1]
                    g2 = interpolated[row - 1][col + 1]
                    g3 = interpolated[row + 1][col - 1]
                    g4 = interpolated[row + 1][col + 1]
                    estimating[row][col] = 0.25 * interpolated[row][col] * (
                        estimating[row - 1][col - 1] / (g1 if g1 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row - 1][col + 1] / (g2 if g2 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row + 1][col - 1] / (g3 if g3 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                        + estimating[row + 1][col + 1] / (g4 if g4 != 0 else interpolated_row_median)
                    )

    return estimating
```

Comment: The pdf of the patent offers a bit more implementation details: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US4642678.pdf

Comment: This looks like a gross implementation error, like wrong indexing or confusion between components. Can we see the original Bayer bitmap ? (uncompressed !)

Comment: @Yves Daoust hi, I think the problem comes when the denominator is zero, the way I handle it is not really correct. Do you have any suggestion about that?

Comment: I don't know the details of the algorithm. What I can say is that a division by zero probably reveals an achromatic color, such that the hue is indeterminate. Then "constant hue" becomes meaningless and you have to switch to an achromatic mode of interpolation.